# Relating Adapter vs facade to Doctrine DBAL, ODBC, JDBC, and ADO.NET

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to understand the age old facade vs adapter confusion.

Most languages and frameworks have a data access library designed for RDBMs. In the case of the examples provided above you have a connection interface, and one connection type for each driver type. All of these types besides ODBC have a ODBC connection type.

Is it correct to assume that these connections are all adapters and not facades?

Is it also correct to assume that the "bridge type" connections e.g. the Ado.NET Odbc connection object and the Jdbc->Odbc bridge are also facades and not adapters,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes concrete connection types in each of these frameworks

1. Concretely each connection type implements a connection interface and possibly inherits from an abstract connection class
2. Conceptually, because we are not attempting to simplify the APIs of each RDBMS. If anything, the data access layers are made more complex by the fact that they are completely open to the incompatibilities of the various RDBMS systems. They are designed to pass or generate SQL between your application and any RDBMS.

In the case of the ODBC bridges, once again these are adapters and not facades. The purpose isn't to simplify the complexities of ODBC. The purpose is to make the ODBC connection adhere to the ADO.NET or JDBC contracts.

Comment: You could give someone else a chance to answer.

Comment: @JeffO I'm sorry is ettiquiet here different from on stackoverflow.com? I thought the point of having to wait two days to self accept an answer was to allow other to peer review self answered questions. Please answer or edit my question appropriately based on deficiencies in my answer.

Comment: I think if you ask and immediately answer a question, it puts a lot of people off to the point they don't bother trying to help you.